# Migrate multiple widget sizes into one widget on ICS and JB

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have a widget that has various sizes defined in AndroidManifest.xml (3x2, 4x1, 4x2).  Now that newer versions of Android allow resizable widgets I'd like to clean up the 3 widgets and just have one resizable widget.  I know how to do that, but how do I migrate users to that 1 entry?

Current version:

```
<receiver android:name=".Widget3x2" android:label="@string/widget_name_3x2">
    ...
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".Widget4x1" android:label="@string/widget_name_4x1">
    ....
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".Widget4x2" android:label="@string/widget_name_4x2">
    ....
</receiver>
```

New version only has 4x2, but I want users of 4x1 and 3x2 to now default to 4x2 without intervention:

```
<receiver android:name=".Widget4x2" android:label="@string/widget_name_4x2">
    ....
</receiver>
```

For example, if a user is using the 3x2 widget and I push an update that only has a 4x2 resizable widget, they're left with a blank space on the home screen.  Is there a way to somehow force them over to the 4x2 without manual steps?

Thanks for your help!